# How to check status of the job scheduled using APScheduler?

Tags: python, apscheduler

I need to check the status of the job, its been difficult for me to get the status(paused/resumed/running).
can anyone guide me how to check get the status of the job?
The jobs are created and scheduled using the APschedular module in python.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way will be to add a event listener described in the documentation (https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/events.html#module-apscheduler.events) and store the job status in db manually on callback. then you can check from db about the status of the job. If you need any custom event, you can implement the event class or manually add that event in the job code.

Comment: Thank you for your response , i have manually added into the db.